# Problemas com javascript ao ler getElementByID no IE e Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Tenho uma problema interessante e não sabia dessa condição no IE. Existe no site que peguei para dar manutenção, uma chamada assim: `document.getElementByID(...)`. Bem, o que ocorre é que o IE não está pegando o `ID` e sim o `Name`, até porque não existe ID e sim Name. Bem, no `Chrome` isso não funciona(correto). O que fiz, alterei as chamadas para: `document.getElementsByName(...)`. Bem, deveria funcionar e não funciona. Dá esse erro em cima do `jquery-ui.min.js`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.plugins[n].push is not a function
```

Esse é o código do meu js. O elemento é `IFConsultaEmpresa_`:

```
if (pObjAsp != 'X') {
         pagina = pTxtDiretorio + pObjAsp + '?pt=' + pTxtNomeFuncao + p_parametros;

         var cp = new cpaint();
         cp.set_transfer_mode('get');
         cp.set_debug(false);
         cp.call('../../atc/asp/atc0006c.asp', 'auxHistNavegacao', '', pCodFuncao, pTxtDiretorio, pTxtNomeFuncao, pNumeroIframe);

         //torna o iframe invisivel
         for (var i = 1; i <= qtd_iframe; i++) {
               //eval('document.getElementById(\'IFConsultaEmpresa_' + i + '\').height = \'0%\';');

               //Essa alteração para ByName foi necessária para funcionar no Chrome
               eval('document.getElementsByName(\'IFConsultaEmpresa_' + i + '\').height = \'0%\';');
               eval('document[\'all\'].IFConsultaEmpresa_' + i + '.style.display = \'none\';');
         }
         eval('boolIFrame = (IFConsultaEmpresa_' + pNumeroIframe + '.location == \'about:blank\')');

         form01.ifram_carregado.value = 'IFConsultaEmpresa_' + pNumeroIframe;

         if (pCodFuncao == 'ATC84.5.4' || pCodFuncao == 'ATC84.5.5' || pCodFuncao == 'ATC84.5.6' ||
               pCodFuncao == 'ATC84.2.2.2' || pCodFuncao == 'ATC84.2.2.3' ||
               pCodFuncao == 'ATC84.8.2.1' || pCodFuncao == 'ATC84.8.2.2'
            ) {
               boolIFrame = true;
         }

         if (!boolIFrame & pNumeroIframe == '1') {
               //iframe1 exclusívo para abertura/encerramento de atendimento - alteração novo atendimento
               boolIFrame = true;
         }
         if (boolIFrame) {
               eval('document[\'all\'].IFConsultaEmpresa_' + pNumeroIframe + '.src = \'' + pagina + '\';');
         }
         eval('document[\'all\'].IFConsultaEmpresa_' + pNumeroIframe + '.style.display = \'\';');
          //eval('document.getElementById(\'IFConsultaEmpresa_' + pNumeroIframe + '\').height = \'50%\';');

          //Colocado para funcionar no Chrome
         eval('document.getElementsByName(\'IFConsultaEmpresa_' + pNumeroIframe + '\').height = \'50%\';');
      }
   }
   try {
      window.parent['roteiro'].location = '../../ace/ace040a.asp?cod_funcao=' + pCodFuncao;
   } catch (e) {}
   if (form01.ind_visualiza_roteiro.value == 'S') {
      try {
         parent.document['all'].td_roteiro.style.display = '';
      } catch (e) { }
   }
}
```

Aqui está o meu html com esse elemento:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="0%" scrolling="auto" name="IFConsultaEmpresa_<%Response.write intI%>" id="Iframe2" src="about:blank" frameBorder="no" style="display:" >
    </iframe>
```

Veja `IFConsultaEmpresa_` é o name e não o ID. Como eu resolvo isso?

Comment: Uma dúvida. Se tem as libraries jQuery na aplicação, por que não usar para evitar esses problemas de cross browser?

Comment: @ErickGallani, boa tarde. Ela está adicionada. Essa é a dúvida porque está dando esse pau. Tenho os includes do jquery. Se eu remover o ByName e deixar o ByID funciona

Comment: então, você está utilizando document.getElementsByName que é javascript nativo. Isso vem com alguns problemas, pois cada browser tem uma maneira de interpretar essa instrução. Esse foi um dos maiores motivadores da criação do jQuery. Você não pode fazer algo como $("[name='IFConsultaEmpresa_' + i + ''']") ?

Comment: creio que não esta dando problema com o jquery.ui e sim com algum plugin que faz uso do jquery.ui

Comment: @ErickGallani, posso tentar sim fazer isso. O nosso grande problema é o seguinte. O site é muito grande, estimamos mais de 2000 páginas, relatórios e etc. Eu mexo apenas em uma pequena parte do site, escrito em ASP. Porem há muitas chamadas que são comuns a outras partes do site. Por isso não é tão simples assim, trocar isso por aquilo. Se esse arquivo é chamada apenas nesse módulo, não há problemas nisso, mas senão, aí teríamos que fazer um estudo bem detalhado para ver o impacto da mudança.

Comment: Certo, entendo bem esse tipo de problema. Você consegue saber qual ou quais componentes são utilizados nessa página em questão que você está mexendo? Por que nem o jquery nem o jquery.ui conflitam com o javascript nativo de nenhum browser. Por isso eu acho que o verdadeiro erro esta sendo mascarado.

Comment: @ErickGallani, então, conversei aqui com o líder, que ele tem uma visão macro dos sistema, ele me disse que esse js só é utilizado nesse módulo, logo farei esse teste chamando por jquery e não por javascript. Uma pergunta: E quanto ao eval()? Coloco o jquery dentro do eval() ou mato o eval()?

Comment: mantenha dentro do eval para minimizar os impactos no seu projeto.

Comment: @ErickGallani, substitui essa expressão: eval('document.getElementsByName(\'IFConsultaEmpresa_' + i + '\').height = \'0%\';'); por essa outra, mas estou apanhando nas aspas, pois acho que o parêntesis está errado: eval($('[name=IFConsultaEmpresa_' + i + '].height = 0%\';'));

Comment: tente assim eval('$("[name=IFConsultaEmpresa_' + i + '"].height = \'0%\';'));

Comment: Continua o erro: Uncaught TypeError: a.plugins[n].push is not a function. Fiz assim: eval('$("[name=IFConsultaEmpresa_' + i + ']").height = \'0%\';');

Comment: @pnet, apenas uma nota `getElementByID` retorna um `Element` enquanto `getElementsByName` retorna um `NodeList`, então para o seu exemplo funcionar, você precisaria acessar o primeiro elemento da lista `document.getElementsByName(name)[0]`.

Comment: @TobyMosque, valeu é isso mesmo. Já havia feito por sugestão de um colega. Vou encerrar o post com a resposta que eu dei, mas muitos comentários me levaram  a solução, principalmente à época do Gallani e esse seu comentário, também valeu, mas eu já havia feito assim por sugestão de um outro colega, mesmo assim obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolvi. Bem, a resulução não por outra pessoa não era possível, apesar de todos aqui me orientarem no caminho. Porque falo isso. Bem, conversando aqui com o responsável, tivemos que duplicar o arquivo .asp para não ter impacto em outras chamadas fora do módulo. Então mudei o ID do elemento para o mesmo do Name. Então foi possível pegar pelo ByID e deu certo. Porque duplicar? Existe em outras partes do sistema uma chamada a ao ID antigo, logo duplicamos e deixamos um arquivo apenas para o módulo em estou e o outro arquivo para os demais módulos. Uma solução porca, mas para um site que já está no ar há mais de 10 anos e sofrendo remendo, tivemos que fazer isso. A empresa estuda uma possibilidade de reescrever o site, mas isso leva tempo. Há custo altos envolvido e a solução não é tão simples assim. A resposta por justiça deveria ser do ErickGallani, pois ele é que me fez ver esse lado da duplicação.

Comment: muitas vezes trabalhando com grande sistemas e principalmente sistemas que estão a muito tempo no mercado sofremos com o legado. Principalmente por que em 110% das vezes não temos tempo hábil para analisar a fundo o problema e escrever uma solução que seja a mais correta. 
Mas estou feliz que você conseguiu resolver seu problema. E é assim, ossos do nosso oficio hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho certeza sobre o erro mas o que você pode fazer é isso

```
if ( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1 ){
  //Faz alguma coisa se for chrome
}
```

Qualquer coisa dá um toque e verifica se esse erro de função não acontece por nenhuma outra particularidade.